# How do I create bidimensional table from list?

Tags: python, list

Starting with a list of tuples which represent points on a surface.

```
list = [(48, 228), (96, 204), (120, 192), ... ]
```

What is the pythonic way to create a new list, so we can call values from the original list, as if they were distributed on a grid?

Like this:

```
>>>print grid[0][0]
(48, 228)
>>>print grid[0][1]
(96, 204)
```

Comment: What do you expect `grid[1][0]` to be? Should values exist for anything above `grid[0][x]`?

Comment: `grid = [list]` would do it, but is probably not what you want. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Tim I'd imagine `(96, 228)`, it was probably a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list comprehension that solves it:

```
l = [(48, 228), (96, 204), (120, 192), ... ]
# 'width' is the width of your bidimensional table (grid)
bidimensional = [l[a*width:(a+1)*width] for a in xrange(len(l)/width)]
```

Explained:

```
[  # make a list of:
  l[a*width:(a+1)*width]
    # get the 'a'-th slice of length 'width' of the initial list
  for a in xrange(len(l)/width)  # for 'len(l)/width' slices
]
```

Test:

```
>>> l = [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44), (5, 55), (6, 66),(7, 77), (8, 88)]
>>> width = 2
>>> bidimensional = [l[a*width:(a+1)*width] for a in xrange(len(l)/width)]

>>> bidimensional
[[(1, 11), (2, 22)], [(3, 33), (4, 44)], [(5, 55), (6, 66)], [(7, 77), (8, 88)]]

>>> bidimensional[2][1]
(6, 66)
```

Comment: Indeed, that solved it nicely. I hope my python voodoo is as strong as yours one day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the difficulty, maybe a simple `grid=[list]` would suffice.

If you want to have it as a fast 2d-array, use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.array(list).reshape(1,-1)
print grid[0,1] #prints (96, 204)
```

If your data become larger or higher dimensional, always use numpy arrays, don't use lists-of-lists.

One remark: please don't call your variable `list`, it will hide the built-in method `list`.